# No qualifying bean of type available, when wiring repository with service

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I do have the following service:

```
@Service
public class PartService {


  private final PartRepository partRepository;

  @Autowired
  public PartService(PartRepository partRepository) {
    this.partRepository = partRepository;
  }
...
```

And it is using the following repository

```
@Repository
public interface PartRepository {


  @Query("SELECT p FROM Part p WHERE p.partNumber = :partNumber and p.partRevision = :partRevision")
  List<Part> findAllByPartNumberAndRevision(
          @Param("partNumber") String partNumber,
          @Param("partRevision") String partRevision);

}
```

However, I do get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.package.PartRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it. It seems like Spring wants me to implement a base interface, such as `JpaRepository`, as well.

```
@Repository
public interface PartRepository implements JpaRepository<Part, PartPK> { ...
```